# How to disable screens on Windows temporarily and quickly?

Tags: windows-10

I'm not sure exactly what I'm after here so I'm going to describe the problem. I have a Windows 10 PC with 6 monitors and every day for some hours I want to use 2 of those monitors for a laptop. I plug in the laptop and switch the monitors to the inputs for the laptop. I want to still use the Windows 10 PC on the other monitors. The problem now is that Windows 10 still sees the 6 monitors and thus there are 2 monitors that are now hidden for me. Windows could go in there and I might not see them.

Is there a way to make this work? To have Windows consider those monitors gone?

I don't particularly want to use a KVM switch because these are 4k monitors running 144Hz for gaming and they can rarely keep up and if they can, they add lag and other issues.

Comment: Perhaps Nirsoft Multi Monitor App.  I use monitor off for one monitor and it works well.

Comment: @John that looks promising. I'll give it a try.